# Can't run my project on Android AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I try to test database on android.I want to run my project in sumsung GALAXY TAB. So,  I set AVD is Galaxy Nexus ,RAM = 512, VM Heap = 64, SD Card = 1024 MiB . I create android project name is SQLiteDatabase . when I run SQLiteDatabase on AVD it show this error.
 
**Unfortunately,SQLite Database has stopped.**

I don't know why I can't run SQLiteDatabase project this is error from logcat.

```
01-09 04:17:27.347: I/Process(6519): Sending signal. PID: 6519 SIG:9
     01-09 04:17:33.517: W/Trace(6848): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
     01-09 04:17:33.517: W/Trace(6848): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
     01-09 04:17:33.562: W/Trace(6848): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
     01-09 04:17:33.562: W/Trace(6848): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
     01-09 04:17:34.917: D/dalvikvm(6848): GC_CONCURRENT freed 75K, 7% free 2744K/2948K, paused 12ms+6ms, total 122ms
     01-09 04:17:34.917: D/dalvikvm(6848): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 71ms
     01-09 04:17:34.937: I/dalvikvm-heap(6848): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.868MB for 1127536-byte allocation
     01-09 04:17:35.027: D/dalvikvm(6848): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3843K/4052K, paused 84ms, total 85ms
     01-09 04:17:35.227: D/dalvikvm(6848): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3847K/4052K, paused 10ms+4ms, total 199ms
     01-09 04:17:35.347: E/SQLiteLog(6848): (1) near "tabletool": syntax error
     01-09 04:17:35.359: D/AndroidRuntime(6848): Shutting down VM
     01-09 04:17:35.359: W/dalvikvm(6848): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlitedatabase/com.example.sqlitedatabase.MainActivity}:
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tabletool": syntax
 error (code 1): , while compiling: create tabletool(idinteger primary
 key autoincrement ,nametext ,amountnumericunitunit
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tabletool": syntax
 error (code 1): , while compiling: create tabletool(idinteger primary
 key autoincrement ,nametext ,amountnumericunitunit
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
 Method)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at com.example.sqlitedatabase.SimpleSQLiteHelper.onCreate(SimpleSQLiteHelper.java:43)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at com.example.sqlitedatabase.ToolDataSource.open(ToolDataSource.java:28)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at com.example.sqlitedatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
     01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlitedatabase/com.example.sqlitedatabase.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tabletool": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tabletool(idinteger primary key autoincrement ,nametext ,amountnumericunitunit 01-09 04:17:35.417: E/AndroidRuntime(6848): at
```

There is no code available in question, but based on above exception stack, it seems you have some syntax error in create table "tabletool"

Make sure create table syntax is valid (spaces, colons etc., are there where required).

Answer (score 1):

Hey in the log I found that your table query is wrong.

Change this query like this

```
create tabletool(id integer primary key autoincrement ,name text
```

I am able to see only two parameters in log in which you have forgot to maintain spaces. put the spaces between parameter and datatype and try it. It works for you.

Check your query you written it as `idinteger` and `nametext` which should be `id integer` and `name text`